# Uploading a pdf file in a folder in a database and saving the path in table

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using Sql compact 3.5, I have some 500 .pdf files to upload in my database, i want to upload the .pdf file in a folder in database and save the path of that .pdf in a table containing the Products list for which this .pdf files belongs to..

I have a scenario that where a single .pdf file belongs many products.
Can you please suggest me that how can I achieve uploading one .pdf for many products and downloading the same .pdf when I search many products...(C#, Windows application)

Answer (score 0):

it easy to upload and download pdf. but remember one thing your file path same in both database and folder which you save this pdf.I am sure that this below link is helpful for upload and download pdf http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/uploading-and-downloading-pdf-files-from-database-using-asp/
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-files-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: But it throws the Error that there is no defination for  ExReader and no Extension method

Comment: @Pavani I voted to reject your Edit to this Answer because you should not change somebody's answer into what code you have at this point. Either update your Question, or if it's short then you can add a comment to an Answer.

Comment: hi. i am help to you. and u blame me. so now i can't update my answer or any more help. you do whatever against me . i don't care.

Comment: @prajapati Extremely sry....! using stack Over Flow  for the fst time and Not sure about asking questions made a mistake in updating a question...

Comment: i post link in my previous link which helpful to you to implement "Uploading a pdf file in a folder in a database and saving the path in table" this very easily. read it carefully and do exact same. if any problem then tell me.i make your help.